# Android architecture: Where should we hold the Cursor(s)?

Tags: android

Scenario:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{...}
```

Three Activities, Overview, List and Map,
displaying the **same data** only providing different UI/UX.

Data fed into Contentprovider db and frequently updated externally by a SyncAdapter,
part of another application.

Read data from Contentprovider in to cursor.
Do cursor.setNotificationUri(),
to make the cursor listen for db/Uri changes.

**Alt1.** Hold the cursor in MyApplication.
Overview, List and Map then asks MyApplication for data.
On a db change MyApplication holds a reference to each Activity
and notifies them to ask for the data again from MyApplication.

**Alt2.** Hold one cursor in each Activity.
On a db change each Activity requeries the cursor for the data again.

**Where should we hold the Cursor(s) ?**

Comment: +1 for the question. Android architecture specifics is really a point to be discussed deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem but not with DB and cursor but simple web request\response.
The problem u'll start facing soon enough is what ahppens when your activity dies in the midst of a request response.
I would suggest the following:

1. make a base activity u'll inherit
   from that will contain a cursor for
   the query.
2. make sure you have a method to fill
   the currsor with data in onResume
   start listening to broadcast
   receiver.
3. when you finish a db update in the
   separate thread, notify all
   receivers.
4. when you perform on create check the
   data in the DB to see if you missed
   a call from the broadcast because your activity
   has died.

so basically u will have a cursor in each activity, but no need to manage it by code unless you need to do something that is not standard with it. don't forget to dispose the cursor once the activity dies.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input. Based on your answer I'm not sure if you are using a custom Application. When AndroidOS ends the life of an Activity the Application still lives. If the Application holds the cursor, we will query only once, but hold references to Activities. If the Activities have one cursor each we will use up more db resources, but no coupling Application<->Activity exists. My question is related to drawbacks and benefits of both approaches.

Comment: Don't assume `Application` lives forever. On a real device it may be killed as a part of killing a background process. For instance, if you get an incoming phone call, then your app goes in background. Your app process will be restored when the app appears in the foreground again (the phone call is finished). On restore the `Application` instance will be recreated, however it is only you who is responsible for handling its state, e.g. if you have some field within the `Application` instance and that field was set by some other part of the app, then now you can get `null` there instead.